# getIndexes returns empty array on MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I'm trying creating indexes on a MongoDB collection and while they are correctly created and they work (I can see the index in the executionStats), the output of the `getIndexes()` function is an empty array:

```
> db.shopOrder.createIndex({'userId': 1});
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.shopOrder.getIndexes();
[ ]
```

I'm using MongoDB 3.6, why does this happen?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `version()` and `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell?

Comment: Thank @Stennie your comment made me realize I was using the old client (ver. 2.6), when I swtiched to the 3.6 one it's all working